# Compilation error in prolog

Tags: compiler-errors, prolog, sum, swi-prolog

I am trying to write a code in prolog which reads two integers from standard input and outputs their sum.
But I am getting compilation error. Please help.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose,silent).
:- prompt(_, '').
:- use_module(library(readutil)).

main:-
    process,
    halt.

process:-
    /* your code goes here */
    readreal(X),
    readreal(Y),
    S = X+Y,
    write(S).
    true.

:- main.
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if we knew the exact error...

Comment: ERROR: -g user:(main,halt): ''/1: Undefined procedure: main/0

Comment: It should be `S is X + Y`. `=/2` is unification, not arithmetic expression evaluation.

Comment: Also, you’re trying to redefine the standard control construct `true/0`. Delete that line.

Comment: Done that. Still giving runtime error. https://ideone.com/SLcJvK

Comment: In your ideone, this is a syntax error: `S is X + Y. =/2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are several issues in your code. Also, there isn't any `readreal/1` built-in predicate in a SWI-Prolog or in its `readutil` library. Simplifying and fixing your code:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose,silent).
:- prompt(_, '').

main:-
    process,
    halt.

process:-
    /* your code goes here */
    read(X),
    read(Y),
    S is X+Y,
    write(S).

:- main.
```

Sample execution (assumed saved in a `code.pl` file in your current directory):

```
$ swipl -g "[code]"
12.
23.
35
```